# CSS: scrolling slideshow not repeating

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a long image that I want to slide on the screen with a scrolling effect, like on the apple tv's webpage (the floating/scrolling movie covers):

this is the markup i use:

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="slider">

        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the css:

```
    .header{
    height: 610px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header .slider{
    height: 540px;
    background: url("../images/header.jpg");
    position: relative;
    border-left: 10px rgb(34,34,34) solid;
    border-bottom: 10px rgb(34,34,34) solid;
    border-right: 10px rgb(34,34,34) solid;
    left: 0;
    top: 60px;
    width: 450%;
    animation: moveSlideshow 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: moveSlideshow 40s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveSlideshow 40s linear infinite;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

}
```

here is the css animation:

```
@keyframes moveSlideshow {
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
}
```

}

it occurs that the slideshow is scrolling but for only once and it soon scrolls out of the screen after the entire image is scrolled(and also with some part of the beginning!)..

the image is:
[image: dimensions: 5526*540]

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do You mean something like this?

```css
@keyframes slide-banner {
  0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
  100% {background-position: -300px 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-banner {
  0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
  100% {background-position: -300px 0;}
}
@-o-keyframes slide-banner {
  0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
  100% {background-position: -300px 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-banner {
  0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
  100% {background-position: -300px 0;}
}
.slide-banner {display: block; width:100%; height:100px; animation: slide-banner 2s infinite linear; -webkit-animation: slide-banner 2s infinite linear; -ms-animation: slide-banner 2s infinite linear; -moz-animation: slide-banner 2s infinite linear; -o-animation: slide-banner 2s infinite linear;}
```

```html
<div class="slide-banner" style="background-image: url(http://www.javatpoint.com/images/javascript/javascript_logo.png);background-repeat: repeat;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the apple tv effect you're referencing, but if you want it to loop over and over you need to add an additional keyframe @ 0% with translateX(0); and then use the width of the image in your @ 100% translateX();

So if you have a 2000px image your animation would look like :

```
@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }
}
```

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/wWMzwe
(!NOTE: I turned on auto-prefixer as you code was busted in everything but chrome !)

Comment: hi, I am still having trouble with my image, I am editing the question with my image, can you please place that image in the above example...? the dimensions are 5526*540

Comment: Your image is there, but the mechanism is detailed above, translateX by the number of Pixels. I strongly recommend not using an image that wide with one continuous transition, it's going cause jitter, Also performance considerations mean a 520kb image is going to be a waste for slower connection users.